# Java Chat application bandwidth usage?

Tags: java, chat, bandwidth

I've tried to look around for data concerning how much of a bandwidth hog a chat application is.

In this case maybe with a Java/AJAX implementation or simply just Java, using Server/Client relationship.

I want to find out, how much bandwidth such a system would use when it's written in Java. The benchmark could be 15-20 users from all over the world and peaking at maybe 8 or 10 max connected at a time. I know it might seem vague, but I simply can't seem to find data on this specific situation.

Can anyone point me to some resources regarding this? Or chip in if possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you can't find data about this is because there's nothing particularly Java- or AJAX-related here. Bandwidth usage depends on the data you send/receive over the network, and therefore is dependent upon the protocol that you design to pass data around; it has nothing to do with whether you use Java only, or AJAX in combination of Java, or CGI scripts, PL/I or Assembler.

You can code a chat application in Assembler that will be a worse bandwidth hog than a chat application coded in Java.

In order to know your bandwidth impact, you need to analyze your data model, data flow and your overall communication protocol: namely, what data is being sent, in what structure, and how frequently.

Comment: I see. I am fairly new to networking so it was something that interested me, since people tell me that chat applications hog a lot of CPU/RAM/Bandwidth. I would imagine that this system is designed around TCP (since I can't afford to drop packages with UDP in a chat application) which got quite a big overhead. Do you know other protocols that might suit this need better?

Comment: When I wrote "protocol", I wasn't referring to TCP vs. UDP. I actually wasn't talking about a networking protocol; I was talking about a data protocol. For example, are you going to use XML to represent data? are you going to compact data into very efficient structures? that sort of thing.

Comment: About CPU/RAM/Bandwidth hogness: CPU/RAM can, indeed, be affected by your choice of API's and frameworks. Bandwidth - it's all up to your data protocol.

Comment: Ah right. I don't know that many data protocols. XML I did know of course. But if I wanted to do a "PUSH when needed" kind of structure (kind of how Steam, made by Valve, works) would that be doable in Java? I mean, would a Connection Pool be able to make up for the amount of resources you use opening and closing sockets rapidly?

Comment: Yes. Once you come up with a data protocol and a strategy regarding when and how to send messages, you can implement it all in Java. Java supports sending any sort of data over the network. A connection pool sounds like a good idea for this. But then again, a connection pool is not a Java-only concept. You can use connection pools in Java, just as you can do it in any other language. For implementations of pooling in Java, read about Java Executors.

Comment: Alright. Thanks for your time. Will accept the answer when it lets me :)

Comment: No problem. Yes, you should accept. No data protocol will ever work for you in a chat application unless you accept this answer; it's a curse.

Answer (score 4):

Unless the chat application is sending photos or files, it will use a trivial amount of data. With a max user count of ten people at once you could wrap the messages in a bandwidth hog of xml and I would still stick with my answer: it will use a **trivial amount of bandwidth**.

Say all ten of your users are fast typers and very chatty. They type non-stop at 100 words per minute. Break that down to 10 sentences per minute and wrap each of these in a message to the server. Add some XML data describing who the message came from and whether it is private to another user or sent to a group of users and maybe you could get 1K per message. So each user is then sending 1K to the server every 6 seconds. With 10 users, we get 10K sent to the server every 6 seconds.

So by my estimate, we could connect your server to a 56K modem from 1995 and you'll be fine.

Comment: That last line made me laugh. You'll get an upvote for that. Also awesome suggestion.